# Python and Floats

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I have this code :

```
N = 10
for i in range(1,N):
    P[i,i] = (i/N) + pow((1-i/N),2)
```

But my division operations are getting rounded down to the nearest integer.

How can I instruct Python to do floating-point division?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers and http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: WTF with the downvotes???  This makes me really mad.  Perfectly valid questions.

Comment: He gave what he has, but not what he expects.

Comment: The `P[i,i]` doesn't make sense in the brief context provided. Consider editing to provide a code snippet that executes and outputs what you claim.

Comment: P[i,i] is an array ... and i want to fill the diagonal with that value ... Has nothing to do with the question. I'm using python 2.7 and yeah i just started. really, don't understand the downvotes. As a newbie i will consider NOT to post any other question.

Comment: @flagant1996 Sorry that Stack Overflow didn't give you the best welcome today. Keep coming back, where else will you get an answer in five minutes?

Comment: @Mario it is completely clear what he wants and what his problem is.

Comment: "what i get is 0,1,1,1,1,1 which is not the thing i want !" That's not explaining what he wants. For the record I didn't downvote.  But I understand why some people would.

Comment: I agree with MK.  It's obvious what he wants.  OTOH, P[i,i] just confuses things.  Also, when I run this, I get nine 1s, not  0,1,1,1,1,1.

Comment: @fragant1996, next time you ask a question, don't include irrelevant items, such as P[i,i], and specify what result you expected.

Comment: @foosion Ok.. will keep it in mind. THANKS !

Comment: Clarified the question so that it reflects what the user is actually trying to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing integer division.  Try something like this:

```
N = 10
for i in range(1,N):
    P[i,i] = (float(i)/N) + pow((1-float(i)/N),2)
```

Comment: Depends on the Python version and whether `from __future__ import division` is present.

Comment: Given his output, he's doing integer division.  I'd also not recommend importing from `__future__` to someone so new to a language.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line to the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This will allow division of integers to give floats with the usual division operator `/`. If you also need to perform integer division, you can use `//`:

```
>>> 9/10 
0.90000000000000002
>>> 9//10
0
```

This will be the standard behavior in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, division between two integers is the mathematical division, but floored. Since you're dividing two integers, one being equal or smaller than the other, you get 1s and 0s.

To have the correct behavior, use floats:

```
N = 10.0
for i in range(1, int(N) ):
    P[i,i] = (i/N) + pow((1-i/N),2)
```

Note that Python 3.x does mathematical division with two integers